# How to change default landing page in Redmine 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, rails-routing

The older methods for Redmin 2.x suggested to change routes.rb to the follwing:

```
root :to => 'wiki#show', :project_id => 'myproject', as => 'home'
match '/', :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'
```

in place of

```
root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'
```

However, this is giving a server error (500), hinting that 3.x needs a different hack to achieve this.
Any Redmine/Rails experts with solutions?

Answer (score 4):

For redmine 3.2.0, it's in the file `config/routes.rb`, replace

```
root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'
```

by this line for the homepage of a project

```
root :to => 'projects#show', :id => '<myproject>', :as => 'home'
```

or by this line for the wiki of a project

```
root :to => 'wiki#show', :project_id =>'<myproject>' ,:as => 'home'
```

`<myproject>` is the identifier of your project, you can see it in the settings page of the project and in the URLs.

Comment: This is very clear and exact.

With all the chatter on the redmine.org forums asking this exact question, you'd think they would clean things up and put it out in plain english for those of us that are using Redmine and don't have the time to become intimately familiar with the code.

Answer (score -1):

example: `</br>`
root :`to => 'my', :action => 'index', :via => :get, :as => 'home'`